# Json não carrega na lib TypeHead

Tags: javascript, jquery

beleza? Tenho um Json cujo tem seguinte estrutura:

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"teste"},{"id":2,"nome":"teste"},{"id":3,"nome":"teste3"}]
```

Quero usar ele neste código do type head mas porém ele não carrega... No console do navegador mostra que carregou o json corretamente.

No retorno do Ajax, já retorno com tipo json...

```
$('#nome').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        objects = [];
        map = {};
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, object) {
            map[object.label] = object;
            objects.push(object.label);
        });
        process(objects);
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        console.log(map[item].id);
        //$('hiddenInputElement').val(map[item].id);
        return item;
    }
});
```

retorna error no console:

> TypeError: b is undefined

Comment: Não vejo `b` no teu código... (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, mudei a chave do json de "nome" para "label" e ai deu certo.